# Algorithm to find the maximum/minimum of a polynomial without graphing.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

For a quadratic equation of the form $y=ax^2+bx+c$ the max/min occurs at $x=-\frac{b}{2a}$. Is there any hard and fast equation like this for polynomials of degree $\geq 4$?. For such polynomials the solution which I got online suggested to plot the curve and find. How to find the absolute maxima without graphing?

Comment: Compute the roots of the first derivative; at these points compute the function value and check the sign of the second derivative. The problem is that, with polynomials of fifth or higher order, you have the same problem. When you can plot the curve, it is really the best way.

Comment: There is no formula for polynomials of degree higher than $4$, so in general you will have to rely on approximate methods which are conceptually equivalent to plotting the graph.

Answer (score -2):

If you have a third-degree one, you can derivate your expression (this is quite easy to do by a algorithm of your own, for polynomials). Then you get the max/min by x=-b'/2a'.

For a fourth-degree polynomial, just derivate again, and then use your previous programm for 3rd-deg to find the max/min !

Once you've got an algorithm for degree n, repeat the operation for degree n+1